# Search for key word and convert the output into new line after it matches in python

Tags: python

I have below List output from the a code which i'm working in python where i'm specifically looking for `memberUid` string and want every names after that to be printed into new line:
like:
anshulm
jiafan

and while prnting these names as soon it will get `'cn'` just stop the print.

```
[[('cn=oracle,ou=Group,ou=corp,ou=services,o=kk.com', {'description': ['oracle group'], 'businessCategory': ['Private'], 'objectClass': ['top', 'groupOfUniqueNames', 'posixGroup'], 'memberUid': ['anshulm', 'jiafan', 'manasij', 'asbisht', 'karnika', 'junle', 'amitsh', 'fuwei', 'dewansh', 'gouravr', 'harshitb', 'tandel', 'matte', 'izamir', 'elie', 'emiliano', 'mateuszw', 'theo', 'mahdi', 'hassan', 'gshruti', 'makhiles', 'prabhaka', 'shgarg', 'ritolia', 'wadhwani', 'steev', 'rtlsbld', 'nikhilb', 'fwang', 'ankitb', 'rtls', 'amitb', 'agautam', 'pratyush', 'hywang', 'dsouder', 'foutz', 'parimi', 'pradeepn', 'patrickg', 'pkunwar', 'tejinder', 'ramteke', 'jangra', 'kush', 'kundan', 'mohang', 'xiang', 'xinjia', 'anantv', 'christos', 'achugh', 'kbhatt', 'jroy', 'kusantos', 'kamleshm', 'iraa', 'indrajit'], 'gidNumber': ['9393'], 'owner': ['varshney'], 'cn': ['oracle']})]]
```

> Below is my code which is yielding the above output:

```
import ldap

## first you must open a connection to the server
try:
        l = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldapserver:389")
        l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
        print e

    baseDN = "ou=group,ou=corp,ou=services,o=kk.com"
    searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
    retrieveAttributes = None
    searchFilter = raw_input("Enter the Group Name: ")
    try:
            ldap_result_id = l.search(baseDN, searchScope, searchFilter, retrieveAttributes)
            result_set = []
            while 1:
                    result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
                    if (result_data == []):
                            break
                    else:

                            if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                                    result_set.append(result_data)
            print result_set
    except ldap.LDAPError, e:
            print e
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free code-writing service

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers,  i understand that, though i'm not askingto write a code just a hint, though i updated my question with code

Comment: Hint #1 : check what your result_set is, eventually copy-paste it into your python shell and find out how to navigate thru it until you get the data you're looking for. If you don't learn how to do such basic things as iterating though lists and looking up keys in dicts then you will not get very far as a Python programmer. You'll learn more by solving it by yourself than by copy-pasting a code snippet you don't understand.

Comment: Hint #2 : your try/expect blocks are currently more than useless: they are harmful. Either properly handle exceptions or let them propagate - at least you'll get the full traceback and your code won't try to continue executing with undefined variables....

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, thanks for your all inputs, i went through your all comments thoroughly and took them positively & appreciate your suggestion. Just saying that i'm a guy who works primarily on clinical pathology and Diagnosis of broad spectrum i  caught into the fathom of love for IT and seamless interest on UNIX & python  and opted to learn for fun and help the guys who can not afford even the paid teaching, I know this forum is not for writing the codes for others but just to help them in way so, those can get an idea from a expert group around.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, again i appreciate your wide wisdom on programming and hope larger people will be getting benefited of your knowledge & suggestions but don't limit it to you only spread it as possible as you can because this is the eara of openness & sharing which anyway don't harm but gears up respects to the wide spread IT spora!

Comment: I understand (and actually appreciate) your irony, but you'd be surprised at how many peoples just come here looking for ready-made solutions that they don't even bother try to understand (but come back and complain when those 'solutions' don't work out of the box).  I might have answered differently if you had posted a bit more context and eventually one attempt at solving the problem).   I'm a self-taught programmer too   and what I suggest is actually how I learned. Also, I  answered hundreds of questions here, most often upvoted and/or accepted.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I see that and appreciate your expertise ! Alas i could have that much Wisdom to understand programming bits so quickly as you but mathematical logic's are like a puzzle for me but even i taught myself lot over UNIX , shell and python a bit as a newbie trying hard to get speedy on it as i love it many ways as i see my friend working on it which facilitates nice things! if sometime i could meet you i will take some lessons from you to get something out of your wisdom of self learning & python of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract desired part from `result_set`, for example:

```
result_set[0][0][1]['memberUid']
```

and print it with any manner you like:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(result_set[0][0][1]['memberUid'])
```

or

```
print('\n'.join(name for name in result_set[0][0][1]['memberUid']))
```

Comment: Roman, i'll try your code and get back to you! appreciate your time.